# Word 2007 Arabic Macro Replace

Tags: ms-word, replace, arabic

I am trying to manipulate Arabic in Word 2007.

I need to find a line that begins with a number. In English docs I would use "^p^#"

But in the Arabic doc I have, this isn't being found. Here's a snippet of text where a line starts with ٦٤ا :

```
- ١٦٤يا معشر البشر تمسّکوا بالحبل المتين  انّه ينفعکم فی الارض
```

من لدی اللّه ربّ العالمين خذوا العدل و الانصاف و دعوا ما امرکم به

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Word's "Use Wild Cards" feature to use Regular Expressions.